# Why call map in macro will fail in my Clojure code?

Tags: clojure, macros

I want to transfer code from

```
("AAA" ("BB"  11 @"XXX"))
```

to

```
("AAA" ("BB"  11 "YYY"))
```

I just want to change `@"XXX"` to `"YYY"`.

I write a function it works.

```
(defn tt  [clause]
      (cond (not (sequential? clause)) clause
            (and (sequential? clause)
                 (= 2 (count clause))
                 (= `deref (first clause))
                 (string? (second clause)))
            "YYY"
            :else (map tt clause)))
```

there is my result:

```
(tt '("AAA" ("BB"  11 @"XXX")))   -->  ("AAA" ("BB" 11 "YYY"))
```

But when I change the `function` to `macro` , it raise exception.

```
(defmacro test [& clause]
    (let [f (fn tt [clause]
              (cond (not (sequential? clause)) clause
                 (and (sequential? clause)
                   (= 2 (count clause))
                   (= `deref (first clause))
                   (string? (second clause)))
                  "YYY"
                  :else (map tt clause)))]
        (f clause)))
```

and it raise exception like this

```
(test "AAA" ("BB"  11 @"XXX")) --> ClassCastException java.lang.String cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

I have test `map` `for` `prewalk` function. Both of them raise exception.
I have no idea what is wrong with it and how to fix this error in macro??

Comment: You'll see exactly the same error if you'll type `("BB" 11 "YYY")` in your REPL.

Comment: You macro works fine, but clojure can't evaluate `("BB" 11 "YYY")` since `"BB"` is not a function.

Comment: you macro return a form `("AAA" ("BB" 11 "YYY"))`,and it should be eval,but the `"AAA"` is not a function